# How do i use Django and UTF-8 content-type for template?

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding, utf-8

When I do:

```
return render_to_response()
```

in Django. How do I set the content-type to UTF-8? So that everything displayed is UTF-8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

django use UTF-8 as default encoding, but this can be modified with settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET.

Be sure, in your HTML template, to set UTF-8 for the HTML page also :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```