# Label for input field isn't rendered when ends with non ASCII character

Tags: python, html, django

I encountered a strange behavior while using Django forms. In my `forms.py` I have a user register form, and for each field I have set a label. Then in view I am passing the form into the context. In html file I'm using the form as follows:

```
{% for field in UserForm %}
<div class="form-group">
    {{field.label_tag}}
    {{field}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

my form looks like this:

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Imię',
        max_length=255,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'name': 'Name',
                'placeholder': 'Imię',
                'required' : '',

            }
        )
    )

    last_name = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Nazwisko',
        max_length=255,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'name': 'Surname',
                'placeholder': 'Nazwisko',
                'required' : '',

            }
        )
    )
```

The problem is that for one field a label is not shown,
the `<label>` tag is not even generated in output html file.

The problematic label is: `label = 'Imię',`. I noticed that when a label ends with non ASCII character, the label is not generated. I tested that for other field labels.

I have included `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the `forms.py` (otherwise python throws an error about non ASCII characters in file), so that's not the source of this problem. Also I checked in Notepad++ that this file really uses UTF-8 encoding.

I'm using Django 1.9 and python version is 2.7.6.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the code from your `forms.py`?

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998987/how-do-i-use-django-and-utf-8-content-type-for-template ?

Comment: @IainShelvington the file is here [link]http://pastebin.com/RYjyRsgj

Comment: @LuisAlves I've got this in my html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2.7 have 2 types of string, normal and unicode. Normal string (used by default) can't store any unicode characters. In your form you are using normal strings for label. That is causing issues.

You can either use unicode in that string:

```
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label = u'Imię',
        max_length=255,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'name': 'Name',
                'placeholder': u'Imię',
                'required' : '',

            }
        )
    )
```

Or set all strings in this file to be treated as unicode by default, by adding:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

At the very top of the file (right after setting encoding for file).

In python 3 that was changed, so by default all strings are treated as unicode.

Comment: Thank you, it works now! I was not aware that the strings are not treated as unicode by default before python 3. I didn't suspect that may be a problem because other strings which contained unicode characters were working good.